# Game info file? LibGDX android

Tags: android, libgdx

In my app I need a file that I can keep settings like: TutorialSkip: True or AppDev: False and other info. How can I make this file and prevent users editing it?

This has to work in the Core folder for my project as it should work with android windows and ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to achieve this is using **Preferences**. Follow [this](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences) tutorial for more information. Good luck.